# C++: namespace specifier for classes and functions

Tags: c++, namespaces

Why for using vector class I should write namespace specifier `std::vector` but for `std::find` function I can omit `std::` ? What is the difference? Both are defined in `std` namespace, right?

Comment: What's the context here? Sample source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why for using vector class I should write namespace specifier std::vector but for std::find function I can omit std:: ?

In general, that is not true.

> What is the difference. Both are defined in std namespace, right?

Yes, and there is no difference in principle. Per Paragraph 17.6.1.1/2 of the C++11 Standard:

> **All library entities except macros, operator new and operator delete are defined within the namespace `std` or namespaces nested within namespace `std`.** [...]

However, you must keep in mind that exceptions are allowed by the rule of [Argument-Dependent Lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup): thanks to this lookup technique, it is not necessary to explicitly specify the namespace of a function, because the name will be looked up in the namespace of the *arguments* you are supplying to that function.

Thus, if the function happens to be defined in the same namespace as any of its arguments, it will be found by the compiler even though its name is not qualified with the namespace it belongs to:

```
namespace N
{
    struct X { };

    void foo(X) { }
}

int main()
{
    N::X x;
    foo(x); // OK
}
```

Thus, if you are calling `std::find()` with some arguments that are instances of types defined in the `std` namespace, you won't need to qualify the call to `find()` with `std::`. For instance:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3 };
    auto i = find(v.begin(), v.end(), 2); // ADL applies if the result of
                                          // v.begin() and v.end() is an
                                          // iterator whose type is defined 
                                          // in the std namespace!
    std::cout << *i;
}
```

Obviously, this can't apply to functions that accept *no* argument. In that case, the namespace qualification is always necessary, unless of course the point of invocation is inside that namespace (although you can't *add* anything to the `std` namespace, some templates from the `std` namespace can be specialized).

Answer (score 1):

At the start, you include libraries to your program (std namespace)
Then afterward you don't need to use all the time the word std.
But in reality all the objects equal std::cout std::cin

std is one of the fundamental libraries of c++

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you call `std::find`... for example if you pass some iterators from std container, this function will be found by [ADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup), otherwise you have to add `std::` to call it.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the STL chose to expose many of the algorithms (in ) in the global namespace. that is why you can just write find(...) or transform(...). Vectors are not exposed so you must either do `std::vector<>()`. Or you can just put using `std::vector;` at the top of your file

Comment: This is not true. From the C++ Standard (17.6.1.1/2): "*All library entities except macros, operator new and operator delete are defined within the namespace std or namespaces nested within namespace std*"